# Pass other data with smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

My application uses a lot of ajax requests to get the data. I am using smarty template on the server side. What I am current doing is detecting if the requesting is AJAX request on the server side and return corresponding html using smarty templates. But now I want to also pass some more data along with html in JSON format. So my JSON format would look like this

```
{"body" : "MY HTML", "data1" : "value1", "data2" : "value2"}
```

Is it possible to do so with Smarty?

Answer (score 0):

u can send multiple value in array with json using this style

**Note:** below is only logic, make it compatible with your`smarty`

```
$return_data= array ('body'=>"MY HTML", 'data1'=>"value1", 'data2'=>"value2")
echo json_encode($return_data); 
//and retrieve on php side (with smarty logic)
$get_json=json_decode($return_data,TRUE);
$get_json['body'];
$get_json['data1'];
$get_json['data2']
```

#### [Reference](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=58281)